Why am I experiencing non-stop long beeps from Gigabyte motherboard?
My PC's specs:

Intel i3-10105f
Zotac GTX 1060 3gb
Gigabyte b460m gaming HD
16gb (2x8) DDR4 ram.
500w Xilience PSU
250gb SSD
2tb and 500gb HDD

Prior to this the PC was running fine.
4 days ago I bought a new GPU, the RX7600.
I did everything as one should do, disconnected the PC, opened up the case, took out the 1060, plugged in the RX7600.
Connected everything back - no signal on display. Strange, I thought to myself.
Rebooted, still the same issue.
Did this about 3-4 times.
It was late, so I thought I'd deal with this problem tomorrow.
Swapped out the RX7600 back with 1060 and everything ran fine.
Next day, swapped the GPUs again, and the RX7600 ran! Installed the drivers, and put the pc to sleep.
Turned it off, then turned back on again and the pc boots, but the gpu is not recognized, HWMonitor does not show GPU, BIOS does not show gpu either.
Turned PC off, swapped out the GPUs back to 1060.
Played 2 hours of days with a friend, everything ran fine, until my game crashed and PC froze.
Restart button didn’t work, so I turned it off by switching off the PSU. When I tried turning it back on again, I get non stop long beeps.
As I've searched the internet, the non stop long beeps should mean that PCIe graphics card is not seated properly.
I disconnected:

The HDD’s and the SSD.
Removed the GPU.
Swapped out the RAM, and later took it out completely.

Problem is still the same.
Thought it might be the PSU at fault.
I have a spare PSU, plugged that one in and the issue is still the same.
Could this be that my motherboard failed on me?

Have you tried plugging into your internal graphics, if you have one?

I've tried plugging both the gpu and the mobo, even though the CPU does not support on board graphics. The issue is the same.

I feel like it has to be the motherboard (or CPU), given that you tried everything else. There's not really much else to be done in this kind of situation.

You did not do everything you should have. You did not appear to take correct esd precautions & therefore you may have zapped any number of components with a few thousand volts of static & therefore destroyed them.

Bob, I didn't. When this happened, I was about 2 hours in gaming, then the pc crashed. I'm pretty sure it was not static electricity. Even if, by some chance, the dust got into the ram sockets, or anything else, the issue would be immediate.

Wholly incorrect. Damage can creep up. I suggest you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0lsHDU2Sr4 & it's other parts.

Have you checked the documentation for this mainboard? The beep codes will often be listed there with information indicating that they mean.
